# R Squared (OOB) and R Square from correlation of prediction of test set is different?

Tags: correlation, random-forest, r-squared, bagging

I'm using simulated data and fitting Random Forest model for regression on a training dataset. What is confusing me is that after running Random Forest, I got R Squared (OOB) equal to 0.14. But when I predict the test set and and find a correlation equal to 0.84 between actual response variable of test set and predicted values of the response. Taking square of of correlation gives me 0.75, which R Squared. My main question is why are they different? Can we use correlation, that is, 0.84 instead of OOB R Squared to check whether our model is good are not? And also what else can I do improve the model? Here are my sample codes

```
######## Import libraries
library(ranger)

######## data
p <- 300
n_train <- 3000
n_test <- 3000
beta <- rnorm(p)
err_train <- rnorm(n_train,mean=0,sd=.5)
err_test <- rnorm(n_test,mean=0,sd=.5)

X_train <- replicate(p,{
  rnorm(n_train)
})

y_train <- X_train%*%beta+err_train


X_test <- replicate(p,{
  rnorm(n_test)
})
sim_test_dat <- data.frame(X_test)

names(beta)=colnames(sim_test_dat)

y_test <- X_test%*%beta+err_test

train_data <- data.frame(y=y_train, X_train)


####### fitting model
ntree <- 5000

RF_mod <- ranger(y~., num.trees = ntree, mtry = 10 ,min.node.size =6,
                 data = train_data, replace = TRUE,
                 importance = "permutation", sample.fraction = 0.8,
                 oob.error = TRUE
                 )#keep.inbag = TRUE

####### Calculating accuracy
pred <- predict(RF_mod, data = sim_test_dat, type = "response")
sqrt(mean((pred$predictions - y_test)^2)) # RMSE of testset

sqrt(RF_mod$prediction.error)
plot(y_test, pred$predictions)
cor(y_test, pred$predictions)
cor(y_test, pred$predictions)^2 # R Squared
```

Comment: How are you calculating each value? I suspect you get the numerator SSE right for both but have different denominators. // $R^2$ does not have its usual “proportion of variance explained” in nonlinear models. // $R^2$ is a function of MSE and gives no model comparison insights beyond what MSE gives. Given that $R^2$ lacks the usual interpretation as an absolute measure of fit (which is dubious in linear models, too) and can overestimate or underestimate that absolute measure of fit, I am not sure why one would want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In OLS linear regression with an intercept, there are two equivalent ways to calculate $R^2$.

$$
R^2=\left(\text{corr}\left(y,\hat y\right)\right)^2\\
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$$

When you use other methods, these need not be equal. In particular, $\left(\text{corr}\left(y,\hat y\right)\right)^2 = \left(\text{corr}\left(y,a + b\hat y\right)\right)^2$ for any real $a$ and any nonzero $b$. Thus, squaring the Pearson correlation between predicted and observed values can lead to thinking that terrible predictions are good, such as $y = (1,2,3)$ while $\hat y=(105, 205, 305)$. In this case, $\left(\text{corr}\left(y,\hat y\right)\right)^2 = 1$, yet the predictions are terrible. The seond calculation will catch tht the predictions are terrible and report a value less than zero.

Your results are completely consistent with this. You get a fairly high squared Pearson correlation and a much lower result from the second calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the R Squared to evaluate your model. The OOB R Squared is used to check the behavior of the bootstrap samples, but what matter at the end is the model as a whole.